# SQL - Iterate over a temp table to check for free DBs names

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do an SQL script here but facing some dificulties as I don't have so much knowledges on that, here is my issue:

I need to create a temp table with pre-determined values (dbrsm01 to dbrsm30) and check iterating through these values if one of them is available on MSSQL server to be used as a new database, if one of these values is already in use it needs to be ignored as I need to create a new DB using this value.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (id int, dbname varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(1,'dbrsm01');
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(2,'dbrsm02');
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(3,'dbrsm03');
...
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(27,'dbrsm27');
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(28,'dbrsm28');
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(29,'dbrsm29');
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(30,'dbrsm30');

DECLARE @maxid INT, @counter INT, @tempname VARCHAR(10), @nameset VARCHAR(10)

SET @counter = 1
SELECT @maxid = COUNT(*) FROM @temp

WHILE (@counter <= @maxid OR @nameset = @tempname)
BEGIN

SET @tempname = (SELECT dbname FROM @temp WHERE id = @counter)
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @tempname)
BEGIN
    SET @nameset = @tempname
END

SET @counter = @counter + 1

END

SELECT @nameset as [@dbname]
```

Any help on that is appreciate! Thank you all!

Comment: Help on what?   Are you getting an error?    What is your question?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, just asking for help on how to implement that kind of code as I said, I've not so much knowledges on SQL coding and I'm trying to do that by myself, I'm not asking for the code to be done, just any kind of help on how to do that. Thank you!

Comment: This has the appearance of an xy problem all over it. http://xyproblem.info/ Why do you need to dynamically determine the name for a newly created database? There seems to be something a bit strange going on here.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't need to be iterative at all. You can do this in a single statement:

```
WITH Tally AS (
    SELECT 1 AS i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i + 1
    FROM Tally
    WHERE i + 1 <= 30)
SELECT 'dbrsm' + CONVERT(varchar(7),T.i)
FROM Tally T
     LEFT JOIN sys.databases d ON 'dbrsm' + CONVERT(varchar(7),T.i) = d.[name]
WHERE d.database_id IS NULL;
```

*Edit: A mindset you need to change when writing SQL is thinking programmatically. You don't want to think about what you're going to do to a row, you need to think about what you're going to do to a column. Using loops are not a way of thinking in a dataset approach (normally).*

*Edit: Nevermind, here's how to make a `CREATE` statement and make all the databases:*

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

WITH Tally AS (
    SELECT 1 AS i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i + 1
    FROM Tally
    WHERE i + 1 <= 30)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(10) + N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(N'dbrsm' + CONVERT(varchar(7),T.i)) + N';'
                     FROM Tally T
                          LEFT JOIN sys.databases d ON 'dbrsm' + CONVERT(varchar(7),T.i) = d.[name]
                     WHERE d.database_id IS NULL
                     FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'');
PRINT @SQL; --This is your best friend for troubleshooting
--EXEC sp_executesql @SQL; --Uncomment to run your dynamic SQL
```

Comment: Thank you so much, as you said I need to change the mindset, I have some much more knowledges on Java, Python and other languages, but almost nothing on SQL. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. if this needs to then execute SQL to create the databases as well, please do comment, and i'll show you how to change the above to do so.

Comment: @JuninhoBill nevermind added a version that doesn't iterate at all for you, and creates the databases.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've left the office for lunch... Actually I just need the value for a new free DB as I'll pass this value to our application at the moment that an analyst will open a request for a new DB, this request will call a WebService and that WebService will create the new DB... I know, I need to prevent the application to open a request if all the slots (1 to 30) is already in use, but I'll do that... So far, thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!! =D

Answer (score 0):

You can use BREAK and do what you want, like this:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (id int, dbname varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(1,'dbrsm01');
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(2,'dbrsm02');
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(3,'dbrsm03');

DECLARE @maxid INT, @counter INT, @tempname VARCHAR(10), @nameset VARCHAR(10)

SET @counter = 1
SELECT @maxid = COUNT(*) FROM @temp

WHILE (@counter <= @maxid /*OR @nameset = @tempname --YOU DON'T NEED THIS */)
BEGIN

    SELECT @tempname = dbname FROM @temp WHERE id = @counter

    PRINT @tempname

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @tempname)
    BEGIN
        SET @nameset = @tempname
        PRINT 'ITS FREE'
        BREAK
    END
    ELSE
        PRINT 'ITS IN USE!'

    SET @counter = @counter + 1

END

SELECT @nameset as [@dbname]
```

If you need to create all DB's that dont exist, remove the BREAK and add your logic (CREATE DATABASE ...)

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql      NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@maxid    INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @temp)
       ,@counter  INT = 1
       ,@tempname VARCHAR(10)
       ,@nameset  VARCHAR(10);

WHILE (@counter <= @maxid)
BEGIN
  SET @tempname = (SELECT dbname FROM @temp WHERE id = @counter);
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @tempname)
  BEGIN
    SET @nameset = @tempname;
    SET @sql = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@nameset);
    PRINT @sql;
    EXEC (@sql);
  END

  SET @counter += 1;
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'CREATE Database '+A.dbname+' 
GO '
FROM
(
  SELECT K.dbname
  FROM @temp K
  LEFT JOIN  sys.databases Y
  ON K.dbName = Y.Name
  WHERE Y.name is NULL
 )A
```

You can copy the result of this statement and run it.

Comment: Thank you so much!!